# Lifting a bijection between $A$ and $B$ to a bijection between $P(A)$ and $P(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that if $f\colon a \to b$ is a bijection then $F\colon P(a) \to P(b)$ is also a bijection. I have completed the four steps to show that $F$ is a function but I am having trouble defining $F$, I do not know what conditions $F$ must meet.

Here is what I have so far.

1.) Showing $F$ is total: X $\in$ $P(a)$ and Y $\in$ $P(b)$
$\forall_x \in$ a $\exists_y \in b$ ( (x,y) $\in P(a) \wedge P(b) \rightarrow$ (x,y) $\in F$ )
$\forall_x \in$ a $\exists_y \in b$ ( $F(x)$ = y )
2.) Showing $F$ is single valued:
Z $\in P(a)$
$\forall_x \in$ a $\forall_z \in$ a $\exists_y \in b$ ((x,y) = (z,y) $\rightarrow$ x = z )
$\forall_x \in$ a $\forall_z \in$ a $\exists_y \in b$ ( $F(z) = F(x) \rightarrow$ z = x )
3.) Showing $F$ is one-to-one:
$\forall_x \in$ a $\forall_z \in$ a $\exists_y \in b$ ( $F(z) = F(x) = y \rightarrow$ z = x )
4.) Showing $F$ is onto:
$\forall_y \in$ a $\exists_x \in b$ ( $F(x)$ = y )

As someone stated in the comments I am unsure of how I showed that $F$ is a function without defining $F$. Hopefully I am just over thinking it, I was told I must use the given function $f$ to define $F$ but can not see how exactly to define $F$.

Comment: If you have already shown that $F$ is a function, how can you have done that without a _definition_ of $F$?

Comment: Please show us what you have done thus far.

Comment: Would a photo suffice? I am still unsure how to type in all of the symbols.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an example. Suppose $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B = \{x,y,z\}$. The following function is a bijection between $A$ and $B$:
$$ f(1) = x \quad f(2) = y \quad f(3) = z $$
The power sets of $A$ and $B$ are:
$$
P(A) = \{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\} \\
P(B) = \{\emptyset,\{x\},\{y\},\{z\},\{x,y\},\{x,z\},\{y,z\},\{x,y,z\}\} 
$$
Can you think of a bijection between $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ inspired by $f$?

Comment: P ({1}) = {x}? So (P(a),P(b)) is an element of F if P(a) is a subset of a and P(b) is a subset of b.

Comment: Yes, $F(\{1\}) = \{x\}$ makes sense. The rest I can't follow. Make sure that you understand what $P(A)$ means: it's the power-set of $A$, consisting of all subsets of $A$. Compare this to $F$, which is the bijection between $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ that you're trying to construct.